# How to enter password in CLI with Robot Framework?

Tags: automation, command-line-interface, robotframework

Test case is a CURL command run locally (No need of Open Connection) wherein I've to enter password upon a prompt. I tried 'Write', 'Input Text', 'Input Text Into Prompt' but it did not enter the password. I've code something like this -

```
${rc}  ${output}=  Run And Return Rc And Output  curl ...
```

This asks for a password during the execution. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can pass the authentication to `curl` command. Below is part of its help:

```
$ curl --help
Usage: curl [options...] <url>
(...)
-u, --user USER[:PASSWORD]  Server user and password
    --tlsuser USER  TLS username
    --tlspassword STRING TLS password
    --tlsauthtype STRING  TLS authentication type (default SRP)
```